# Running make from cmake on external dependency - Forget cmake make rules

Tags: c++, c, cmake, makefile

I'm working with some in-house software that uses it's own Makefile build system. However the software I'm writing needs a bit more flexibility so I'm using CMake which I'd like to configure to build those projects automatically. I'm trying to include these external libraries with their own special build rules via a function like so:

```
set(MyModuleDir "/path/to/my/modules")
set(MyModules "")
function(import_my_module module_name)
    add_custom_target(build_my_${module_name} ALL
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} library
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MyModuleDir}/${module_name})
    add_library(my_${module_name} STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(my_${module_name}
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MyModuleDir}/${module_name}/lib${module_name}.a)
    add_dependencies(my_${module_name} build_my_${module_name})
    include_directories(${MyModuleDir}/${module_name})
    set(MyModules my_${module_name} ${MyModules} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

The command it ends up running is correct, say for dostuff library:

```
cd /path/to/my/modules/dostuff && /usr/bin/make library
```

Which, if run on it's own, produces correct results. However, inside the CMake makefile execution I instead get some warnings about overriding old recipes and then a bunch of errors as it fails miserably while trying to build, like these:

```
cd /path/to/my/modules/dostuff && /usr/bin/make library
make[3]: Entering directory '/path/to/my/modules/dostuff'
../my-make/Make.common:1007: warning: overriding recipe for target '/dostuff'
../my-make/Make.common:982: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/dostuff'
../my-make/Make.common:1032: warning: overriding recipe for target '/dostuff'
../my-make/Make.common:1007: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/dostuff'
I. -I..    -o /myfile -c myfile.c
make[3]: I.: Command not found
../my-make/Make.common:1145: recipe for target '/myfile' failed
make[3]: [/myfile] Error 127 (ignored)
I. -I..    -o /myfile2 -c myfile2.c
make[3]: I.: Command not found
... etc ...
```

So I guess maybe some of CMake's makefile configuration is getting injected in the execution of the other Makefiles. That, or execution from the make context is not allowing the child make process to configure itself properly. I would like to build these projects with a fresh make configuration, without inheriting anything from other make processes. How can this be done?

Here are some of the lines in question from the external makefile:

```
 980 # Target for objdir's executable.
 981 $(execute): $(siblibs) $(library) $(maincobjs) $(mainccobjs)
 982     $(maincppobjs)
...
1004 # We make the libraries for each project, which causes all the object
1005 # files to be created.
1006 $(dynlib): $(siblibs) $(library)
1007    @if [ "$(dynlib_ok)" = "1" ]; then \
1008        cd $(OBJDIR); \
1009            $(linkcc) $(dynlib_link_flags) \
1010                $(LFLAGS) \
1011                -o $(notdir $(dynlib)) \
1012                $(foreach sobj,$(sibobjs), ../$(sobj)) \
1013                $(notdir $(libcobjs)) \
1014                $(notdir $(libccobjs)) \
1015                $(notdir $(libcppobjs)) \
1016                $(LIBS) $(user_libs); \
1017    else \
...
1030 $(library): $(libcobjs) $(libccobjs) $(libcppobjs) $(cplibs)
1031 # numsources must be positive.
1032    @if [ "$(numsources)" -eq 0 -a "$(nummains)" -eq 0 ]; then \
1033        echo "There are no sources to compile or libs to be made."; \
1034        exit 1; \
1035    fi
1036 # Check that sources (incl. main) do not include both libs and c files,
1037 # or multiple libs.
1038    @if [ "$(numcplibs)" -gt 0 -a "$(numsources)" -gt 1 ]; then \
1039        echo "Error: cannot have source files (not incl. main) and"; \
1040        echo "libs {$(cplibs)}, or multiple libs, in same project"; \
1041        exit 1; \
1042    fi
```

Comment: Does the CMake generated Makefile use `cd /path/to/my/modules/dostuff && /usr/bin/make library` literally or does it use `cd /path/to/my/modules/dostuff && $(MAKE) library`? You could also try adding `env` or `printenv` as a command to that recipe to see what the environment at that point looks like. That might tell you something.

Comment: It uses the first. No variable needs to be expanded. I'll try printing out the environment variables and see if anything useful pops out.

Comment: The variables look right. It doesn't show me why there exist recipes that need to be overwritten or why it's trying to run the command I. (cc and cxx are correctly defined).

Comment: Is `my-make/Make.common` a CMake controlled file or part of the "external libraries"?

Comment: External library. The makefiles for individual projects are pretty bare, just specifying a few files and configurations with the bulk of the process being configured by Make.common.

Comment: Can we see `my-make/Make.common` lines 982, 1007 and 1032?

Comment: I added lines from Make.common.

Comment: So now I need to know what `$(execute)`, `$(dynlib)` and `$(library)` contain. Given the error message I assume that at the moment they all contain `/dostuff` presumably because other variables failed to be set correctly. You can try adding `-p` to the cmake rules to get make to dump out the make database at you (so you'll see all the rules and variables in the output).

Comment: Is there a reason, in general, why executing a make command from within CMake should be any different than executing it directly? I'm not understanding why any of these variables should be set incorrectly in one context and not the other.

Comment: Barring differences in the environment? Not that I can think of offhand. When you compared the environments before was there anything missing from the cmake run environment that might be relevant?

Comment: I had only cherry picked a few elements that looked alright, but in fact after a diff it looks like the make environment variables that are set in the Makefile aren't actually being set. Seeing that it's obvious why it's failing, but it's still not obvious why they're not being set when invoked from CMake.

Comment: What variables that are set where? The environment that runs make shouldn't be affected by variables set *inside* that makefile so I wouldn't expect them to be there. Unless you mean recursive make variables that normally exist but don't when cmake triggers the recursive make call? In which case that might be the use of `/usr/bin/make` instead of `$(MAKE)` in the generated makefiles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84833/discussion-between-anthony-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was elsewhere in the common makefile script. There was some code to conditionally set some internal variables based on a check of MAKELEVEL to avoid redefining variables on recursive runs. This gets set by CMake's make scripts (mine was at level 4, for example). So I just updated my command to

```
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} library MAKELEVEL=0
```

And now everything works.